# How Do I Handle errors in Windows Applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-3.5, exception

I did a program and in some point - when the program needs to exit he throw an exception 
here is the code

```
try
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
catch (ExitException) { }
```

In the VS it's working fine (VS 2008 - C#)
But when I run it separately from the VS - the program say so the error is not handled

I know so I can do like this `Application.ExitThread()` - But... I need to handle the exit of the program.

1. Why In VS its work fine and outside its create errors?
2. And how to solve it without using the global error handling?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [AppDomain.UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)
The event handler gets a parameter of type `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` that has the property `ExitApplication` if set to false the application will not exit after the exeption handler.

Comment: Thanks
But This is a global error handling....
I want so it will work as if VS ruining it